# As3.0 syntax error in cs4 but not error in cs5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I'm try to copy code in  cs5 to cs4 I'm got syntax error

[this is code](http://pastebin.com/BgPnaYnd)

I'm got error

[error pic](http://img5.uploadhouse.com/fileuploads/14827/14827159c8d8d7da4871d841bde7127048dbd6d9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your copy and paste is missing a character?

Post your actual code.

I can only surmise that in Flash CS4 you're targeting Flash Player 9.

Your error states general syntax issues, and XML error.  You're using a Vector.<int>.

Either try targeting Flash Player 10, or change the Vector to an Array.

Comment: What player version are you targeting in CS4?

Comment: My work in CS4.
And I have some code from CS5.
I do not understand why it does not apply to the CS4 version.
It's the same AS 3.

Comment: Are you targeting Flash Player 10 in CS4?

Comment: I do not know.
Because I did not get it.
I do not know?

Comment: "File" - "Publish Settings" - "Player"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
I see it as a Flash Player 10.

Comment: And I have tried a Vector variable as Array, but I still like it orrer.